# Kill app on incoming phone call

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

Hopefully an easy one for someone, but causing me problems.

I have an app that loops sound files. I have no code in onPause as I want the app to continue playing music in the background.

I now need the app to close if an incoming call is received.

I can add code to onPause and close the activity and stop the mediaplayer. However this stops the app if any app is launched.

How can I detect an incoming call to check for inside onPause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To detect the incoming call, we register a BroadcastReceiver for the
>   action android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE. This will be broadcasted
>   when there is a change in phone state. The receiving intent will have
>   an extra string variable TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE which describes
>   the phone state. If this state is TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING
>   then there will be another extra string variable
>   TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER. This variable contains the
>   incoming phone number. Note that this variable will not be present
>   when the state is not TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.

source : http://www.androiddevblog.net/android/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android

basically, once you register a broadcast receiver you can listen for the broadcast notification you are interested in your phone, and then act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ... this is just what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to.  Android takes care of it  pausing your app - you have to use telephony manager to determine whether to stop your aplication or not. Proper way would be to handle this in onPause() method